# Terraform - Foreach - Default value

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm a newbie in the Terraform world. Excuse me in advance if this is a dumb question.

This is my conf file:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    google = {
      source  = "hashicorp/google"
      version = "~> 4.75.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "google" {
  credentials = file(var.credentials_file)
  project = var.project
  region  = var.region
  zone    = var.zone
}

resource "google_cloudfunctions_function" "all" { 

    for_each = {
        fct1 = {
            name = "bob"
            git_folder = "bob_folder"
            var1 = "pikachu"
            var2 = "red"
            available_memory_mb = 256
        },
        fct2 = {
            name = "bill"
            git_folder = "bill_folder"
            var1 = "pidget"
            // var2 <-- no need here
            // available_memory_mb <-- default value will be ok here
        }
    }

  name = each.value.name
  environment_variables = {
    VAR1 = var.var1 // OR each.value.var1 IF DEFINED ?
    VAR2 = each.value.var2 // OR DEFAULT VALUE IF UNDEFINED ?
  } 

  trigger_http = true
  available_memory_mb = // "default value if not defined on fct
  [...]

  source_repository {
    url = "https://source.developers.google.com/projects/[...]/moveable-aliases/${var.git_branch}/paths/${each.value.git_folder}"
  }
}
```

Like you've seen, I'm just trying to write all my google functions with their specific params. I don't succeed to specify default params than can be overwrite by specific params.

How can I tell to Terraform : "For this function, takes default param if undefined" ?
Or maybe : "For this function, don't takes var.* param but the one defined here" ?

Comment: What does "undefined" mean? You provide a variable with a default value or you don't provide the variable at all?

Comment: Why not just make `var1` and `var2` into `vars = {VAR1: "pikachu", VAR2: "red"}` and then just doing `environment_variables = each.value.vars`!?

Comment: to @MarkoE : I would like to not provide all possible variables for each item in the foreach loop. If I don't provide one of them, Terraform stop and return `This object does not have an attribute named "var2"`.

Comment: To @luk2302 : because I want to be able to defined "default" environment_variables and not repeat it on all items. Maybe there is a way to defined a default environment_variables JSON and just some keys to be modified for each item ?

Comment: Then you can [`merge`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/merge) the default and actual values.

Comment: Oh ! That seems to be a great way of doing this ! I'll try that and update this topic if it works. Thx !

Comment: This is working well for environement variables. But how can I do the same thing with simple attributes. Like "available_memory_mb"  in my edited question ? Is there something like `~merge(var.defaultattr,each.value.attr)` ? Like in python : `dict.get(key, default = "default value")` -> `available_memory_mb  = each.get('available_memory_mb', default='var.available_memory_mb')` ?

Comment: `available_memory_mb= lookup(each.value,"available_memory_mb", var.available_memory_mb)` seems to do the job ! If it's not a bad practice, I'll add clean answer.

Comment: Using `lookup` is perfectly fine, not at all bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working as expected :

**variables.tf**

```
variable "function_env" {
    default = {
        var1 = "A"
        var2 = "B"
    }
}

variable "function_params" {
    default = {
        runtime = "python311"
        available_memory_mb = 512
    }
}
```

**main.tf**

```
resource "google_cloudfunctions_function" "all" { 
    for_each = {
        funct1 = {
            name = "Billy"
            env = {
                var1 = "C"
            }
            runtime = "python310"
        },
        funct2 = {
            name = "John"
            env = {
                var2 = "D"
            }
        }
    }

    // Mandatory variables that needs to be defined for EACH item :
    name = each.value.name
    // Optionnal variables that can be defined for each item. If not, default in variables.tf :
    environment_variables = merge(var.function_env, each.value.env)
    runtime = lookup(each.value,"runtime", var.function_params.runtime)
    // Variables that can only be change by variables.tf :
    available_memory_mb = var.function_params.available_memory_mb
    // Constant variables that can't be change for each item. Always the same :
    timeout = 60
}
```

Tell me if this is not best pratice !